# Better Rep Tracking

Tags: support, reputation

I often come to Stack Overflow to find that my reputation score has changed. I want to know what it was that made my rep go up (or down). There is the rep graph on my profile page, but this only shows me the total rep gain and total rep loss for a question/answer. This is great if I remember how much rep I had gained/lost on all of my questions/answers previously... but I don't know. Could we see how much rep we gained/lost in a given time period from what questions/answers? Seeing that I gained 40 rep from an answer is good. Seeing that I gained 10 today, 20 yesterday, and 10 a week ago is better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click the envelope next to your name, then go to the reputation tab. Edit dates in URL to taste or use links on page to specify time.

Comment: Actually that is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't even know it was there. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I use my own [reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/stackoverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx). I've got it set up to let you easily see what's happened today or what happened yesterday - I find this a bit simpler than going into the version on Stack Overflow (and it predates it).

Internally there are options to show several days or a specific date, but I've currently hidden them to avoid the SO server getting overloaded with JSON requests :)

The important point (for those interested in rep) is that both of these treat a day as a UTC day - in other words, the same period as the rep cap.

Comment: don't you LIVE in UTC? So you're a dirty timezone cheater!

Comment: Technically, we're BST (GMT+1) at the moment ;-p

Comment: Or "Europe/London" as I prefer to unambiguously call it :)

Comment: You found his secret, Jeff! He has such a high rep, because he is a UTCer. Change SO timezone to New Zealand and he is lost ;-)

Comment: Yup. Think it's a coincidence that the two top rep scorers are in the UK? Conspiracy!

Comment: modos is better http://sof.modos.org/tracker/update/{user number here}

Comment: @Will: It depends what you're after. The modos tracker doesn't easily tell me what's happened for the whole of today, which is important in terms of caps etc. Each to their own - variety is good :)

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Jon's rep tracker. It's better than SO's which is *very* crappy in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a period in the graph to the left of the reputation summary to only see your changes for that period.  Either drag with your mouse, or use the entry boxes below the graph.